# Rapidminer, how to split column?

Tags: split, rapidminer

I have a table like this:

```
id      | animals       | 
------- |:-------------:| 
1       | cat, dog, fish| 
2       | dog           |
3       | cat,          | 
4       |               |
5       | fish, cat     | 
6       | dog           |
```

etc ..
The only possible value in animal  column, is cat, dog, fish or nothing.

And i would like to have table like this:

```
id     | cat | dog |fish|
------ |:----|-----|----|
1      | 1   |1    |1   |  
2      |     |1    |    |
3      | 1   |     |    | 
4      |     |     |    |
5      | 1   |     |1   | 
6      |     |1    |    |
```

Is there any way how to do this in RapidMiner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way

You can use Nominal Value Modificatior called **Split**
The parameters should be set like this: 
attribute filter type:  single 
attribute : animal 
split pattern : , 
split mode :  unordered_split

Be sure that input animal is configured as nominal attribute.